# How get admin url in js file?

Tags: magento2, admin, javascript

How get admin url in js file ?
Js file call AjaxController and this Js file are called to System -> Config from system.xml

Comment: have you checked my updated answer?

Comment: is your issue fixed?

Answer (score 3):

You can try this `this.values.baseUrl;` in your js and you can also refer `/var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/magento2-base/lib/web/mage/app/config.js`

When you see admin page view source, [image]

you have admin base url, so you can get this base url using `window.values.BASE_URL` or may be `window.BASE_URL`.

Comment: have you tried this 'this.values.baseUrl;'? check my updated answer.

Comment: I have not succeeded, but I made a block

Comment: try `window.baseUrl`.

Comment: or try `window.BASE_URL`

Comment: is there any other way for same ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use php code to get AjaxUrl :

```
var requestUrl = <?php $this->getUrl("..."); ?>
```

Comment: I need in JS file not phtml file, I don't have a phtml file in my case

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/123819/this-geturl-javascript-magento-2 This may help you.

Comment: i want to direct get in js file ... i try to use mage/url but that not working in admin

Comment: @NavinBhudiya you can place this php url into some html tag and then can retrieve that url in js file or you can use knockout way. add your url into knockout string and retrieve it in js file and use it

Answer (score 0):

kindly check [here](https://www.rakeshjesadiya.com/base-url-in-js-file-backend-area-magento-2/) it will works.